# Create new Object to replace values in an immutable Object

Tags: java

I have immutable objects as follows.

```
@Getter 
@Builder 
class MainDetail {
    // 5 other String fields
    private Data data;
}

@Getter 
@Builder 
class ImageUrl {
    private final String dataOne; // looking to change these 2 values
    private final String dataTwo; // if rest call returns null for these. 
}
```

Information to fill these up is fetched from a rest call, working fine as follows.

```
List<MainDetail> featureBenefits = // value from a rest response
```

I wish to switch out the dataOne and dataTwo values in here if it is null for each MainDetail Object.

I can't just use a set method to do this cos it is immutable.

I end up with the following verbose way of doing it where I need to do multiple variations of the check to swap values.

I can't just check one at a time and switch cos Object becomes immutable. Can't add another if the second one is null too after that.

Is there a way to do this more elegantly, possibly via streams? Appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
List<MainDetail> mainDetails = new ArrayList<>();
for (MainDetail mainDetail : featureBenefits) {
    if (mainDetail.getImageUrl().getDataOne() == null && mainDetail.getImageUrl().getdataTwo() == null) {
        ImageUrl imageUrl = ImageUrl.builder()
                .dataOne("default1")
                .dataTwo("default12")
                .build();
        MainDetail detail = MainDetail.builder()
                .imageUrl(imageUrl)
                .build();
        mainDetails.add(detail);
    }
    else if (mainDetail.getImageUrl().getdataOne() == null) {
        ImageUrl imageUrl = ImageUrl.builder()
                .dataOne("default1")
                .build();
        MainDetail detail = MainDetail.builder()
                .imageUrl(imageUrl)
                .build();
        mainDetails.add(detail);
    }
    else if (mainDetail.getImageUrl().getDataTwo() == null) {
        ImageUrl imageUrl = ImageUrl.builder()
                .dataTwo("default2")
                .build();
        MainDetail detail = MainDetail.builder()
                .imageUrl(imageUrl)
                .build();
        mainDetails.add(detail);
    }
}
```

Comment: From what I know, I don't really know if this gets any more elegant. Sure, you could use Streams with a filter and map, but you still have to filter based on the nullable properties and then build new objects in those cases.

Comment: @Gregg. Thanks. Could I get an idea on how that would look like in this case to map and filter this. I couldn't do something like   featureBenefits.stream().filter(detial -> detial.getImageUrl().getDataOne() == null); and go from there. That would miss out on dataTwo.

Comment: This code doesn't really make sense.  First, if neither `getDataOne()` nor `getDataTwo()` return null, the code doesn't do anything (i.e. 2 binary conditions implies 4 possible results).  Also, in the second and third blocks, if the data item tested is null, you provide a default value but don't set the other data item.  This looks like a classic use for `Optional#orElse()`, as in oleg.cherednik's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this one:

```
List<MainDetail> featureBenefits = Collections.emptyList();
List<MainDetail> mainDetails = new ArrayList<>();

for (MainDetail mainDetail : featureBenefits) {
    ImageUrl imageUrl = mainDetail.getImageUrl();

    mainDetails.add(MainDetail.builder()
                              .imageUrl(ImageUrl.builder()
                                                .dataOne(Optional.ofNullable(imageUrl.getDataOne()).orElse("default1"))
                                                .dataTwo(Optional.ofNullable(imageUrl.getDataTwo()).orElse("default2"))
                                                .build())
                              .build());
}
```

Comment: Dang, I forgot about using Optional. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

If you are not limited to sticking with standard builders then you could add your own methods for providing default values:

```
class ImageUrl {
    private final String dataOne; // looking to change these 2 values
    private final String dataTwo; // if rest call returns null for these. 

    public ImageUrl withDefaultDataOne(String value) {
        return dataOne == null ? new ImageUrl(value, dataTwo) : this;
    }
            
    public ImageUrl withDefaultDataTwo(String value) {
        return dataTwo == null ? new ImageUrl(dataOne, value) : this;
    }
}
```

Then your translation code becomes:

```
for (MainDetail mainDetail : featureBenefits) {
    ImageUrl imageUrl = mainDetail.getImageUrl()
        .withDefaultDataOne("default1")
        .withDefaultDataTwo("default2");
    mainDetails.add(MainDetail.builder().imageUrl(imageUrl).build());
}
```